# Node.js Dealing with Async

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to get my head around the async nature of node.js.
I've got a express route below which I know won't give the the data I need. Essentially the first mysql query works 100% as expected and the json data that gets returned in res.json is correct. However within this first mysql function I call another function 'getOrderLines()' which always returns '{"Item":[]}' instead of the data I expect it too.

I understand this is happening because of the async nature of node however I can't seem to get around the problem, I've looked into promises and written some basic promises but can't get it to work for the below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
router.route('/salesOrders')
    .get(function (req, res) {
            mysql.query("QUERY", function (err, sql1) {
                    for (i = 0; i < sql1.length; i++) {
                        json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder[i] = {
                            "Id": sql1[i].Id,
                            "AccountReference": sql1[i].AccountReference,
                            "SalesOrderDate": sql1[i].SalesOrderDate,
                            "SalesOrderAddress": [{
                                "Forename": sql1[i].billFirstname,
                                "Lastname": sql1[i].billLastName,
                                "Address": sql1[i].billAddress1
                            }],
                            "SalesOrderItems": {}
                        };
                        json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder[i].SalesOrderItems = getOrderLines(sql1[i].Id);
                    } // End first For loop.
                    res.json(json);
                };
            };
            getOrderLines = function (orderId) {
                var orderLineJson = {
                    "Item": []
                };
                mysql.query('QUERY', function (err, sql2) {
                    for (j = 0; j < sql2.length; j++) {
                        orderLineJson.Item[j] = {
                            "SKU": sql2[j].name,
                            "QtyOrdered": sql2[j].quantity,
                            "UnitPrice": sql2[j].price
                        };
                    }
                });
                return orderLineJson;
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `return` when dealing with asynchronous operations. I would recommend learning and practicing promises. They are a bit difficult to understand at first, but once it clicks I think you will prefer them to continuation passing and you can go from there.

For now, you need to learn to work with callbacks. Promises still use callbacks. Pass a callback to an asynchronous function and call it when its asynchronous operation is done:

```
function getOrderLines(orderId, cb) {
    mysql.query('QUERY', function (err, sql2) {
        // handle err

        cb(/* processed data */)
    });
}
```

You pass that callback in when you call `getOrderLines` and this allows you to use the value that was passed to it:

```
getOrderLines(sql1[i].Id, function (err, result) {
    res.json(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

getOrderLines is an asyntask, calling this way will return empty array

```
    ..SalesOrderItems = getOrderLines(sql1[i].Id);
```

Use async module

```
var async = require('async');

router.get('/salesOrders', function(req, res) {

  // your object here
  var json = {
    Company:{
      SalesOrders: {
        SalesOrder: []
      }
    }
  }; 

  var getSalesOrder = function(callback){
    mysql.query("QUERY", function(err, sql1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sql1.length; i++) {

        // push item into array
        json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder.push({
          "Id": sql1[i].Id,
          "AccountReference": sql1[i].AccountReference,
          "SalesOrderDate": sql1[i].SalesOrderDate,
          "SalesOrderAddress": [{
            "Forename": sql1[i].billFirstname,
            "Lastname": sql1[i].billLastName,
            "Address": sql1[i].billAddress1
          }],
          "SalesOrderItems": {}
        });
      }

      // job done, trigger next function;
      callback();
    });
  }

  var getOrderLines = function(callback) {
    var orderLineJson = {"Item":[]};
    var dataLength = json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder.length;

    for(var i=0; i<dataLength; i++){

      // do what ever you like with orderId
      var orderId = json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder[i].Id;

      // async query
      mysql.query('QUERY', function(err, sql2) {
        for (var j = 0; j < sql2.length; j++) {
          orderLineJson.Item.push({
            "SKU": sql2[j].name,
            "QtyOrdered": sql2[j].quantity,
            "UnitPrice": sql2[j].price
          });
        }

        json.Company.SalesOrders.SalesOrder[i].SalesOrderItems = orderLineJson;

        // check for the last item
        if(i == dataLength-1)
          callback();
      });
    }
  }

  // run async sequentially
  async.series([getSalesOrder, getOrderLines], function(err, result){
    // finally send the json
    res.json(json);
  });
});
```